# How to find out the full path to the python interpreter on mac and how to build a system on the Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I followed the instruction on the *Python Crash Course: A Hands-On Project-Based Introduction* by Eric Matthes to configure Sublime Text for Python 3 on Page 9.

```
$ type -a python3

python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Here is the instruction on the book:

[image: Book instruction]

I encounter the following problems.

1. Could someone explain every details of the command "$ type -a python3", especially the sign "$", and what does this command mean? Because when I type this command in the IDLE, it returns

   ```
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   ```

   to me, and when I type it in the Terminal, it returns

   ```
   File "<stdin>", line 1
   $ type -a Python3
   ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   ```

   to me.
2. Then I tried to launch Python Launcher and I find the full path of the interpreter. Then I followed the command to build a new system. But when I built the command `print("Hello World")`, it returns

   ```
   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6: can't find '__main__' module in ''
   [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
   [cmd: ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6', '-u', '']]
   [dir: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS]
   [path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
   ```

   to me.

Comment: The $ indicates that the command `type -a python3` is to be entered in a shell, not the python interpreter.

Comment: @meissner_ : When I type the command "type -a python3" in the Python 3.6.3 Shell, it still returns "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" with "python3" in pink to me. This is my first time to get in touch with Python.

Comment: This kind of 'type' is not the same as 'type' in python ... in a regular terminal, like sh, bash, zsh, type tells you what command lies behind an alias. so it will resolve 'python3' to whatever path is appropriate.

Comment: General hint: in my experience books differentiate between terminal shells and python by using '>' before python commands and '$' before terminal commands.

Comment: @meissner_ : Thank you very much! You point out the main problem. But there is a new problem right now. Because I installed and uninstalled Python many times, the result shows me 5 python3: two are "python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3", two are "python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3" and the last one is "python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3". How to remove 4 of them?

Comment: Just take the installation/deinstallation method you already used and try to find out how you can tell the installation software which version you want to remove. For example: if you were using apt-get you could tell that app about the version with 'apt-get uninstall apache2=2.3.35' but i don't know how that works in detail on your platform, however a google search should help there rather quickly.

Comment: @meissner_ :Thank you very much for your patience and help! I have figured it out. I really appreciate your generosity. Thank you!

Comment: (When presenting answers here, please do not splice them into your question - the result is difficult for new readers to understand and learn from. Instead, please post an answer below. Thank you.)

Comment: @halfer : Thank you for your new edits. I am new to the python community. I will follow what you told me next time.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author).*

I attach solutions behind each problem that I encountered.

1. *Provided by @meissner* : You need to distinguish the difference between commands run on the Python and commands run on the Terminal. Commands with "$" in front should be run on the clean Terminal; otherwise, they are referred to Python commands.
2. The reason for my problem is that I did not save the file first before I ran the command `print("Hello World")`. Once I save the file, even if the file is empty without any command, then the command could be executed normally.